# Determining record updates which were not applies - Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two files; Update and Current.

Update consists of the same # of type of fields that Current does, only with more of the content populated. I've ran a dozen or so queries to apply records from Update to records within Current.

So now I expect that a few hundred records on Update have a matching record in Current. I want to determine the Updates that were NOT made, which should be records on the Update file that don't match.

I tried to do a join on all fields where one of them was NULL, but that didn't work as expected.

**What logic can I use to pull all records from Update where there isn't a matching record (all fields included in the comparison) in Current?**

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want an outer join where one side is always NULL, something like the following

```
SELECT Update.*
  FROM Update
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Current ON Update.key = Current.key AND Current.key IS NULL
```

Comment: Basically I want all from Table A EXCEPT Table B since there are instances where a row in table B should be an exact match to a row in table A. So if I have 40 columns, I'll need to account for NULL on all of them? And please correct me if I'm wrong, but Access doesn't support OUTER joins, only unions right?

Comment: Difficult to answer as you've provided no details of the tables. As for outer joins in Access see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: I believe I may have found a solution. I assumed that I needed to add a NULL and/or JOIN condition for every column in both tables. It seems as if I just needed to JOIN on one field where it was NULL.

Comment: Good luck with it :-)